# Flash AS3 Array and Sorting

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

My problem is I Have an isometric grid, just based on the X,Y values:
Each time you click a button for instance road than this item is pushed to an array()

```
 //
 addChild(roadTiles);
 gameAssets.push(roadTiles);
 arrangeAssets();
 //
```

My arrangeAssets method just checks the array "no point posting as it fails most of the time.gennerally some items update but not all.
So im hoping some one has a solution to check X,Y value then setChildIndex of Array.
I have looked, keep getting reffered to 3rd party as3 engines which im not interested in as i want to make my own and have better understanding.

[image]

or is this not possible as im only using an X,Y grid

```
    arrangeAssets();{
var i:int = gameAssets.length;
while(i--){
    if (getChildIndex(sortedItems[i]) != i) {
        gameAssets.sortOn("y", Array.NUMERIC);
        setChildIndex(gameAssets[i], i);
    }
    }
```

I only add the items on top of the grass grid into the array.

Comment: I think you are going to need to take another stab at explaining what you are looking to do.  Start with posting your current `arrangeAssets` code, and give an example of a new roatTiles instance you want to push into gameAssets and how it should be handled.

Comment: I'm still having a hard time understanding, can you specify what you want the sorting to do vs what it is doing? or is this not a sorting related question?

Comment: do you want the item you click on to go to the top of the display list, based on the array that you're trying to sort?

Comment: if i was to add a buiding on this grid, than directly behind it add another what happens is the second building overlaps the first building sometimes, or some other times it dissapears until i add another structure than it re-appears

Comment: I think I get now. you have a tile like the semaphore, that gets covered by the street above.

Comment: correct, if i had buildings instead of roads you could really see the difference but i deleted them as im messing with all the roads tiles first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming that  the left most point is `x: 0, y:0` the tiles are covering each other going from a high `x` and low `y` to a low `x` and high `y` values.

I would add a `weight` variable (call it what you like), and calculate it from `(totalx - x) * y`

this would have the top-most corner have a value of 0, and the bottom most have the highest value. every row (diagonal really) would be the same.

Then sort on the `weight` and you have a list of items in the relative z stack.

this doesn't really address the setchildIndex, because you can't have two items there. a hack would be to remove all and add them back in the order. (you could have a temp child, that you add as children to, that way you don't have to remove the children as it is done automatically)

I found this image that shows the `weight` as `_y`from http://www.kirupa.com/developer/isometric/depth_sorting.htm

[image]  [image]

the _y is the same because `(totalx - x) * y` values horizontally are the same

Comment: sounds interesting but its over my head, lol i will ponder with this thought for now thanks i cant get my head around weight value? where did he come from

Comment: it is calculated, imagine the grid as a diamond, the top is at the back with the lowest weight number, and the bottom is the front with the highest.

Comment: Iv read that several times its not the theory thats making me ponder its the formula, how to impliment this method by adding this"weight";

Comment: `totalx` is the number of rows(or columns) along the x axis, I had `x - totalx` instead of `totalx - x` I edited the answer

Comment: i chose your answer im understanding a bit thanks for the help, its now time to implement this to practise